# React table, editable with pagination and 20k rows performance issues

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have an React table that contains 20k+ rows and some of these rows contains editable fields. I e.g. have a number field in which I have a component where it is possible to +/- the value.

I have been using the [Examples: Editable Data](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/editable-data) from react tables own page, where all data is stored in as `useState` and then on each update it is changed - this however performes very badly, as the re-render delays the value changes when clicking the `+` button multiple times. Is there a way to handle this better and maybe also keep the original data such that is it possible to do a "reset", such that I don't need to overwrite the entire dataset for the table.

Comment: Hard topic. I would look into how I load first data, if its loaded in batches per page then I would display only first page and load element accordingly to the page. Then I would store eventual changes in the new create array and just in the end on final request combine it with old value, so you dont need to work on 20k rows constantly. 
This is of course just a theory from my side, but its very hard topic.

Comment: I would really try to remove additional data models that later needs to be merged, currently i have added a `debounced` hook, such that i don't update each time a value is changed but delay it a bit - that works for now but i don't understand if `react-table` don't have some best practices to handle these cases

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on the topic and found that you could use [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized).

> React components for efficiently rendering large lists and tabular data

It seems that it would be perfect solution to your problem.

Whats very cool is that by default all react-virtualized components use `shallowCompare` to avoid re-rendering unless props or state has changed.

Hope this will be a good replacement for `react-table`